# Writing HTTP POST Request in Java

Tags: java, json, http, post, postman

## JsonObject.addProperty(property,value) Clarifications

My current createAuth() HTTP POST Requests works fine as tested with Postman with the following details with the raw JSON content as the Body.

```
{
    "datetimeAccepted": null,
    "adminAuthorizer": {
        "adminId": 1
    },
    "lock": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

However, I am facing issues with writing the exact same Body as a JsonObject in Java with a snapshot of my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvD8z.png).

```
JsonObject authDetails = new JsonObject();
authDetails.addProperty("datetimeAccepted", (Boolean) null);
authDetails.addProperty("adminAuthorizer", // To Write);
authDetails.addProperty("lock", // To Write);
```

How do I go about writing the Java code for this Body? I thank you in advance for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it something like below:

```
JsonObject authDetails = new JsonObject();
authDetails.addProperty("datetimeAccepted", (Boolean) null);

JsonObject adminDetails = new JsonObject();
adminDetails.addProperty("adminId", 1);
authDetails.add("adminAuthorizer", adminDetails);

JsonObject lockDetails = new JsonObject();
lockDetails.addProperty("id", 1);
authDetails.add("lock", lockDetails);
```

Comment: Thank you @pcustar! Will try it out!